# Get IE object to control flash buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, internet-explorer

In the following code there are buttons in the flash which i am trying to make it accessible by html buttons. so when record button is pressed the mode will be "record" and the   `record_functions()` is called.I am able get it working on Firefox  but in internet explorer the buttons wont seem to work i.e, the flash functions cannot be called from internet explorer. please let me know how to resolve this issue

```
 function thisMovie(movieName)
 {
 if (window.document[movieName])
  {
     return document.getElementById(movieName);
  }
 if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
  {
    if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
      return document.embeds[movieName];
   }
  else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
  {
   return document.getElementById(movieName);
   }
  }


 function record_functions(mode)
 {
  if(mode == "record")
  {

     thisMovie("audiorecoding").startRecording();
  }
  else if(mode == "stop")
  {
     thisMovie("audiorecoding").stopRecording();
  }
  else if(mode == "play")
  {
        thisMovie("audiorecoding").playRecording();
  }
  else if(mode == "pause")
  {
        thisMovie("audiorecoding").pauseRecording();
  }
 }

 <input type="button" onclick="record_functions('record')" value="Record" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take your swf by an `id` attribute on IE, but by a `name` attirbute in other browsers.

```
if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") == -1)
    swfObject = document["mozillaEmbedName"];
else
    swfObject = window["ieObjectID"];
```

Comment: Is the above correct or window.document[movieName];And a note for any other user having the same problem.classid has to be included in the object tag else the swf will not be accessible from html buttons.I have used window.document[movieName]; and is working fine for me

Comment: Yes, both window["ieObjectID"] and window.document["ieObjectID"] variants work. My variant is used in adobe's help. I made mistake. I mixed IE and Mozilla. But a current version is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the error you get, if it is a reference error (can't find flash)

I suggest using swfobject that will return a reference to your object, check this out: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/