# How can you make a SWF audio stop when you click on a specific link?

Tags: flash

everyone.
It's about a live support chat. When a member wants to contact me, the chat is ringing (so this swf audio file starts playing). Whenever swf audio alert starts, I get a link: "user X wants to chat, click here to respond". 
After I "click here" a new pop up window (the chat) opens, but the swf audio keeps playing without ever stopping, it's like answering the phone, talking but still ringing.
I tried the function doStop(); - not working. I tried attaching to the "answering link" different commands but couldn't make it. How can this be solved?

Here is the link opening the chat

```
$json['msg'] = 'You have a chat call <a href="#" onClick="return mbetter(\'http://mysite.com/chat/?chat_session='.$rows['id'].'\')">Click to accept</a>';
```

Here is the function "mbetter" that helps me open the chat in a pop up window

```
<!--function mbetter(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=610,width=550');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;} // -->
```

The script for player:

```
function getPlayer(pid) {
var obj = document.getElementById(pid);
if (obj.doPlay) return obj;
for(i=0; i<obj.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var child = obj.childNodes[i];
    if (child.tagName == "EMBED") return child;
}}

function doPlay() {
fname = "chatalert.wav";
var player=getPlayer("audio1");
player.play(fname);}

function doStop() {
var player=getPlayer("audio1");
player.doStop();}
```

And I don't know if this helps, but I'll post it just in case, the object:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
width="1"
height="1"
id="audio1">
<embed src="wavplayer.swf?gui=mini&h=20&w=300&sound=chatalert.wav&"
    bgcolor="#ffffff"
    width="1"
    height="1"
    allowScriptAccess="always"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
/></object>
```

So, the short question would be, how can you make a swf stop playing after you click on a link (pop up) , since you don't need that alert anymore? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect html code. Try this:

```
 <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
         id="audio1" width="1" height="1"
         codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab">
     <param name="movie" value="wavplayer.swf?gui=mini&h=20&w=300&sound=chatalert.wav&" />
     <param name="quality" value="high" />
     <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
     <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
     <embed src="wavplayer.swf?gui=mini&h=20&w=300&sound=chatalert.wav&" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
         width="1" height="1" name="audio1" align="middle"
         play="true" loop="false" quality="high" allowScriptAccess="always"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
     </embed>
 </object>
```

You may find more about javascript/flash interaction on the [Adobe help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary).

**UPDATE**

Try to get a swf object by this javascript code:

```
if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") == -1)
    swfObject = document["audio1"];
else
    swfObject = window["audio1"];
```

Comment: Emin, thanks for the code, still not working, I think it's an Internet Explorer error causing it. I used debug tool and it says  'undefined' is null or not an object for the line: player.play(fname); Shoul I start a new thread? I'm not sure if I'm allowed.

Comment: There is no need to start a new thread. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819186/get-ie-object-to-control-flash-buttons/8822827#8822827) I describe how to get a swf object on IE and other browsers. See an update of my post.

Comment: Emin, I inserted the code, still nothing. IT is so sad to lose members because of a browser issue. :( I put that code right after mine. Could this be the problem?

Comment: 1. Yes, it could. Try to replace your code by mine. 2. You may use Firebug on Firefox to control javascript errors. 3. Are you shure that you call a **javascript** method `doStop()`? Where do you call it?

Comment: I replaced all my code with yours, so the error is now: instance[name] = function () { 
    return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));
This only happens in Explorer, I don't get any error in Firefox

Comment: Does the `doStop` method work on Firefox? What version of the IE do you use?

Comment: Can you stop an audio on Firefox? Try to add flash by SWFObject: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/